# How to combine grouped text one by one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below,

```
        text  group
0      hello      1
1      world      1
2       it's      2
3       time      2
4         to      2
5    explore      2
6        one      3
7       more      3
8       line      3
```

I want to combine each word in text in new column one by one like below,

```
        text  group                     result
0      hello      1                      hello
1      world      1                hello world
2       it's      2                       it's
3       time      2                  it's time
4         to      2               it's time to
5    explore      2       it's time to explore
6        one      3                        one
7       more      3                   one more
8       line      3              one more line
```

so Far I tried,

```
df['res']=df.groupby('group')['text'].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
df['result']=df[['text','res']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join( x['res'].split()[:x['res'].split().index(x['text'])+1]),axis=1)
```

Above code works for the above problem. yet it has some issues.

If I have repeated text index will gives me first element position, it fails on this data

```
        text  group                     result
0      hello      1                      hello
1      world      1                hello world
2       it's      2                       it's
3       time      2                  it's time
4         to      2               it's time to
5    explore      2       it's time to explore
6        one      3                        one
7       more      3                   one more
8       line      3              one more line
9      hello      4                      hello
10  repeated      4             hello repeated
11     hello      4                      hello #this must be hello repeated hello
12      came      4  hello repeated hello came
```

Note: It failed at group 4.

moreover my script is obviously ineffective.

Can some one suggest a way that resolves my index issue and performance issue?

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easy working with function `cumsum` with `string`s, but here is one possible solution - first add space to end, use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and last remove space from right side by [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df['text'] = df['text'] + ' '
df['res'] = df.groupby('group')['text'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum).str.rstrip()
```

Alternative:

```
df['res'] = df['text'].add(' ').groupby(df['group']).transform(pd.Series.cumsum).str.rstrip()
```

---

```
print (df)
       text  group                   res
0    hello       1                 hello
1    world       1           hello world
2     it's       2                  it's
3     time       2             it's time
4       to       2          it's time to
5  explore       2  it's time to explore
6      one       3                   one
7     more       3              one more
8     line       3         one more line
```

Another solution:

```
f = lambda x: [' '.join(x[:i]) for i in range(1, len(x)+1)]
df['res'] = df.groupby('group')['text'].transform(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby` in list comprehension:

```
df['res'] = [' '.join(d.text[:i]) for _, d in df.groupby('group') for i in range(1, len(d)+1)]

print(df)
        text  group                        res
0      hello      1                      hello
1      world      1                hello world
2       it's      2                       it's
3       time      2                  it's time
4         to      2               it's time to
5    explore      2       it's time to explore
6        one      3                        one
7       more      3                   one more
8       line      3              one more line
9      hello      4                      hello
10  repeated      4             hello repeated
11     hello      4       hello repeated hello
12      came      4  hello repeated hello came
```